# Define a range as all cells that contain a certain value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Is it possible in excel to define a range to include every cell in a column that contains a certain value? So, if Column A has a list of City names, Detroit, Chicago, etc. would I be able to automatically select all instances of "Chicago" even if they are in random order without using a VBA macro?

Comment: I think VBA is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

yes:

Select the range you want to search.  A column, let's say.

Then hit `ctrl+F` to find.

Enter in your values (ie'Chicago') in the `find what` field.

Then hit `Find All`.

This will bring up a box below with all the addresses of matches.

Click on one match.

Then hit `Ctrl+A` to select all.  You will see all results highlighted.

Then when you look at your sheet all 'Chicago' cells will be selected.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the reply. Is it possible to have this selection as a dynamic named range? I can assign a name to this selection, but ultimately I'd like any new rows for "Chicago" to automatically be added to the range. Also, if the column is sorted, the named range won't be accurate anymore.

Comment: @RockHopper no you would have to do this each time